# como puedo agregar varios productos a una categoria woocommerce?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

He estado intentando agregar aproximadamente 200 productos a una categoria pero no encuentro la solución de esto. ¿Habría alguna manera de hacer directamente desde el dashboard de wordpress? ¿O se podría hacer con SQL en la base de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Andá a /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product
Donde dice acción en lote, seleccioná "editar", seleccionas todos los productos que quieras agregar categorías, das click en "Aplicar" y te salen todas las opciones de edición masiva.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpTLi.png

Answer (score 0):

Lo más rapido es utilizar un plugin para importar productos con CSV a Woocommerce.

Existen varios, intenta con este: https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-csvimport/